# Allocate weekend day FSCalendar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fscalendar

I use [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar).

How i can **allocate weekend** day? For example in **red color** is **weekend**, other **days** except **weekends** is **blue**. I means to **allocate** not **day** of the **week** (like a **sunday, saturday**), namely **day**, i.e. **date**:

Monday is 0 - blue color

Tuesday is 1 - blue color

...

Saturday is 5 - red color

Sunday is 6 - red color

Monday is 7 - blue color

...

Saturday is 12 - red color

Sunday is 13 - red color

and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the **weekend / weekday** calculation in your `willDisplayCell` method using this extension method for `Date`:

```
extension Date {
  var isWeekend: Bool {
    return NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!.isDateInWeekend(self)
  }
}
```

Depending on whether it is weekend or weekday, set your `FSCalendarCell`'s following properties:

```
cell?.eventIndicator.numberOfEvents = 1
cell?.eventIndicator.isHidden = false
cell?.eventIndicator.color = isWeekend ? UIColor.red : UIColor.blue
```

Comment: In method `cellForDateAtMonthPosition` you means to create cell?
`let cell = let cell = calendar.cell(for: date, at: .current)` and on finish `return cell!`?

Comment: Yes. Dequeue a cell. If the dequeued cell is nil, then create your own cell and return it.

Comment: I understand, but where i take `identifier` for `dequeueReusableCell`?

Comment: Alright, then do all the logic that I mentioned in my answer in the ‘willDisplayCell’ method. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

i found solution for display weekday name in two character. And also you can change color  of weekday label  i mentioned below please check.

```
let weekdayEnumerator = calender.calendarWeekdayView.weekdayLabels
weekdayEnumerator.forEach { (cell) in
let c = cell
let str = c.text ?? " "
c.textColor = UIColor.red
c.text = String(str.dropLast())
}
```